# Cassandra bucket splitting for partition sizing

Tags: cassandra, time-series, datastax, partition, bucket

I am quite new to Cassandra, I just learned it with Datastax courses, but I don't find enough information on bucket here or on the Internet and in my application I need to use buckets to split my data.

I have some instruments that will make measures, quite a lot, and splitting the measures daily (timestamp as partition key) might be a bit risky as we can easily reach the limit of 100MB for a partition. Each measure concerns a specific object identified with an ID. So I would like to use a bucket, but I don't know how to do.

I'm using Cassandra 3.7

Here is how my table will look like, roughly:

```
CREATE TABLE measures (
  instrument_id bigint,
  day timestamp,
  bucket int,
  measure_timestamp timestamp,
  measure_id uuid,
  measure_info float,
  object_id bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((instrument_id, day, bucket), measure_timestamp, measure_id)
);
```

I thought of adding the object_id as a partition key, but then I loose the "flow of measures" made by an instrument, as what interests me is seeing all the measures made by an instrument in a specific day or period of time.

- So the question is, when I want to request all the records of a day for a specific instrument, how can I do if there is many buckets?
- If I want the partition limit to be 400 000 rows, how can I know when inserting data in which bucket I have to insert the data?
- Is there a way of knowing the number of buckets there is?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should focus on your requirements, and then go back to your schema model. In your case, how many measures per day each instruments can do? If each one can do less than your 400k measures then you're already done without bucketing. If your instruments can perform up to 10M measures each, then **N=10M/400k** buckets should be enough to satisfy your requirements. Assuming **N** buckets, when you need to query all the measures coming from a particular instrument you have to perform **N** queries, one for each bucket, unless you can count the measures during your writes, so that you can change bucket when a bucket is full. I mean, you write the first 400k measures in the bucket 0, then you write the second 400k measures to the bucket 1, and so on. Then you need to keep track of on how many **K** buckets you inserted data and perform only **K** queries instead on **N**. That way you have unbalanced buckets (and partitions), but you get your results in the smallest number of queries. If you prefer a balanced-bucket approach instead, you can perform each write in a uniformly distributed random bucket number, but then you have to perform all of your **N** queries to get all the data of a specific instrument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is I don't know how many measures an instrument can do. I mean as they detect objects, the number of objects doesn't have a limit. But ok I can do as you say :)
So there is no 'built-in' way to "count" the number of buckets written? And how does it work when inserting data?

Comment: @Miwauke Don't you know the *speed* of your instruments? If one instrument have a *throughput* of one measure per second then in one day there will be at maximum **M=86400** measures per day per instrument. If the *throughput* is 1k measures per second then you have **M=86M** measures per day per instrument.You don't need an *exact* number, a (ballparked) guess should be fine. **You** decide in which bucket you write your data: each instrument should count its own measures and should write accordingly to the correct bucket with the correct *measure count per bucket*.

Comment: I don't know the speed of the instruments yet but I can investigate. Thank you for your answer, so I have to keep track of "everything" in order to write in the correct bucket, this is what I wanted to know. What is the best way of counting the number of entries in one bucket? Shall I use a counter column somewhere?

Comment: In a bucket? You mean in a partition? `SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE instrument_id=1 AND day='2016-09-23' AND bucket=4`.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant in a partition. 
Thank you for this query I forgot we can do that! Thanks a lot for answering all my questions :)

Comment: @xmas79 How would one handle concurrent inserts into a partition with this model? Say I want to keep a partition size capped at 1000 records, and I have concurrent users writing to this partition, how can I reliably get the count for a partition *and* insert so as not to have more than 1000 records per partition?

Comment: @user1571307 You should know how many users perform inserts and design/tune the model on that. If you don’t have this number and all the users are “standalone” (everyone inserts its own data) then inserting the user id in the partition key solves the problem. BTW this answer assumes each instrument as a “standalone” instrument. I don’t know your specific case, but unless you have also the user id in the table (eg each instrument of each user) then your model doesn’t fit here.