# Cassandra get latest entry for each element contained within IN clause

Tags: cassandra, cql

So, I have a Cassandra CQL statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE APPLICATION_ID = ? AND PARTNER_ID = ? AND LOCATION_ID = ? AND DEVICE_ID = ? AND DATA_SCHEMA = ?
```

This table is sorted by a timestamp column.

The functionality is fronted by a REST API, and one of the filter parameters that they can specify to get the most recent row, and then I appent "LIMIT 1" to the end of the CQL statement since it's ordered by the timestamp column in descending order. What I would like to do is allow them to specify multiple device id's to get back the latest entries for. So, my question is, is there any way to do something like this in Cassandra:

```
SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE APPLICATION_ID = ? AND PARTNER_ID = ? AND LOCATION_ID = ? AND DEVICE_ID IN ? AND DATA_SCHEMA = ?
```

and still use something like "LIMIT 1" to only get back the latest row for each device id? Or, will I simply have to execute a separate CQL statement for each device to get the latest row for each of them?

FWIW, the table's composite key looks like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((application_id, partner_id, location_id, device_id, data_schema), activity_timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activity_timestamp DESC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IN is not recommended when there are a lot of parameters for it and under the hood it's making reqs to multiple partitions anyway and it's putting pressure on the coordinator node.

Not that you can't do it. It is perfectly legal, but most of the time it's not performant and is not suggested. If you specify limit, it's for the whole statement, basically you can't pick just the first item out from partitions. The simplest option would be to issue multiple queries to the cluster (every element in `IN` would become one query) and put a `limit 1` to every one of them.

To be honest this was my solution in a lot of the projects and it works pretty much fine. Basically coordinator would under the hood go to multiple nodes anyway but would also have to work more for you to get you all the requests, might run into timeouts etc.

> In short it's far better for the cluster and more performant if client asks multiple times (using multiple coordinators with smaller requests) than to make single coordinator do to all the work.

This is all in case you can't afford more disk space for your cluster

***Usual Cassandra solution***

Data in cassandra is suggested to be ready for query (query first). So basically you would have to have one additional table that would have the same partitioning key as you have it now, and you would have to drop the clustering column `activity_timestamp`. i.e.

```
PRIMARY KEY ((application_id, partner_id, location_id, device_id, data_schema))
```

`double (())` is intentional.

Every time you would write to your table you would also write data to the `latest_entry` (table without `activity_timestamp`) Then you can specify the query that you need with in and this table contains the latest entry so you don't have to use the limit 1 because there is only one entry per partitioning key ... that would be the usual solution in cassandra.

If you are afraid of the additional writes, don't worry , they are inexpensive and cpu bound. With cassandra it's always "bring on the writes" I guess :)

Basically it's up to you:

1. multiple queries - a bit of refactoring, no additional space cost
2. new schema - additional inserts when writing, additional space cost

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much what I was thinking, but I'm fairly new to Cassandra, so just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. I'm already doing an extra write per insert to another table that's keeping track of some other stuff, so it probably wouldn't be a big deal to just have yet another table that just keeps track of the latest entries. I think it'll help performance out, and performance is definitely more important here than the little bit of space it will consume :)

Comment: Ok then you are all good then ;) man this project looks very interesting :) oh and what are the frequencies with wich the devices write. Consider using bucketing if it's something that writes more often let's say every couple of seconds or more often I can give some suggestions ;) just say frequencies

Comment: I'll have to look into that - I haven't heard of bucketing. The write frequency is currently every 5 seconds per "container", and the number of containers will hopefully continue to grow quickly, so there will be x number of writes per 5 seconds, which could potentially be a whole lot.

Comment: This is around 17k entries per day per 'bucket' we had similar load and we bucketed by month. Basically all the data from one sensor for a month was in a month partition. It all depends on load. Here is an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446962/cassandra-bucket-splitting-for-partition-sizing also try to google. This will save you a lot of trouble down the road ;)

Comment: I also found a bit late update for your problem was looking in something else, it looks like never versions of cassandra will support per partition limit: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryColumnsSort.html So basically you can use `PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;` but I would stay away from versions other than 3.0.X for a while, they seem a bit unstable.

Comment: Ah, cool. I'm already using a newer version of Cassandra, and it looks like it does support this PER PARTITION LIMIT clause - that clause performs quite nicely for the dataset that we have. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition is not suitable for such use of the IN clause. Indeed, it is supported on the last field of the primary key or the last field of the clustering key. So you can:

- swap your two last fields of the primary key
- use one query for each device id